# I can't get "optirun intel-virtual-output" to work in my udev script

Tags: nvidia, udev

I have a thunderbolt 3 dock that I wanted to automate to automatically run a script once it is plugged in and plugged out. I am able to run my "plug out" script perfectly but my "plug-in" script does not work. I have test it manually and everything seems to work fine. But having udev run it doesn't seem to play nicely. I am unable to find any errors thrown by udev. Any helps works.

/etc/udev/rules.d/81-thinkpad-dock.rules

```
SUBSYSTEM=="input", ACTION=="add|remove", ENV{ID_VENDOR_ID}=="17ef", ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}=="3083", TAGS=="power-switch", RUN+="/etc/sbin/thinkpad-dock.sh"
```

/etc/sbin/thinkpad-dock.sh

```
#!/bin/sh -e

sleep 1

username=adam

if [[ "$ACTION" == "add" ]]; then
  DOCKED=1
  logger -t DOCKING "Detected condition: docked"
elif [[ "$ACTION" == "remove" ]]; then
  DOCKED=0
  logger -t DOCKING "Detected condition: un-docked"
else
  logger -t DOCKING "Detected condition: unknown"
  echo Please set env var \$ACTION to 'add' or 'remove'
  exit 1
fi


function switch_to_local {
  export DISPLAY=$1
  VIRTUAL_OUTPUT_PID=$(ps aux | grep -i "intel-virtual-output" | awk 'NR==1{print $2}')
  kill -9 "$VIRTUAL_OUTPUT_PID"
  su $username -c '
        xrandr --output eDP1 --auto --primary \
                --output VIRTUAL1 --off \
                --output VIRTUAL2 --off'
}

function switch_to_external {
  sleep 10
  su $username -c 'optirun intel-virtual-output'
  logger -t DOCKING "finished running"

}

case "$DOCKED" in
  "0")
    #undocked event
    switch_to_local :0 ;;
  "1")
    #docked event
    switch_to_external :0 ;;
esac
```

Comment: Why use `/bin/sh`? `bash` is better. `su` is probably failing because it can't prompt for password. `sudo` is better, read `man sudo sudoers`. A `udev` script doesn't have the same `$PATH` as your desktop - use absolute paths. Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Comment: @waltinator changed my commands to sudo su $username -c '...' and changed from sh to bash. Sadly no difference :(. Any other ideas?